# there is a "Alphanumeric" option for adonis js5 Validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

Hi everybody i end of to read the documentation of adonis js for to use "validation rules" but i dont see a option for to validate a "alphanumeric" value(in adonisjs 4.1 this exist but i try to migrate to adonis 5), i have the way of to make this rule but before i need to question ¿Really there not is a alphanumeric validation in validation rules or i need to read the guide again? and ¿there is some platform for ican to send my custom validation rules? Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Use the `regex` helper rule to implement an alphanumeric rule.

From the [docs.](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/validator/rules#rulesregex):

```
{
  username: schema.string({}, [
    rules.regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)
  ])
}
```

This will allow these:

```
username10 // --> OK
username // --> OK
Username10 // --> OK
```

while disallowing these:

```
user_name // --> BAD
user-name10 // --> BAD
USER@name10 // --> BAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a rule called `alpha`, you can check it out here: https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/validator/rules#rulesalpha

Or just create a [Custom Rule](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/validator/custom-rules) or regex.